ValueError: Failed to parse the ONNX file
When I converted TensorRT's engine and set the batch_size of ONNX to 16, the code showed the following error
...

[10/30/2024-16:36:59] [TRT] [I] Found regisitered local function: stylesync_model_ToRGB_generator_to_rgbs_6_1. Checking as a local function.
[10/30/2024-16:36:59] [TRT] [I] Found regisitered local function: stylesync_model_ModulatedConv2d_generator_to_rgbs_6_conv_1. Checking as a local function.
[10/30/2024-16:36:59] [TRT] [I] Found regisitered local function: stylesync_model_EqualLinear_generator_to_rgbs_6_conv_modulation_1. Checking as a local function.
[10/30/2024-16:36:59] [TRT] [I] Found regisitered local function: stylesync_model_Upsample_generator_to_rgbs_6_upsample_1. Checking as a local function.
[10/30/2024-16:36:59] [TRT] [I] Found regisitered local function: aten_constant_pad_nd|inlined_40. Checking as a local function.
[10/30/2024-16:36:59] [TRT] [I] Found regisitered local function: aten_constant_pad_nd|inlined_41. Checking as a local function.
[10/30/2024-16:36:59] [TRT] [E] In node -1 with name:  and operator:  (convMultiInput): UNSUPPORTED_NODE: Assertion failed: checkSpatialDims(kernel_tensor_ptr->getDimensions()) && "The input tensor shape misaligns with the input kernel shape."
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_convert_engine.py", line 26, in <module>
    feature_engine = build_engine(feature2image_path, precision='fp16')
  File "/autodl-fs/data/digital_human/SSCODE/convert_tensorrt.py", line 27, in build_engine
    raise ValueError('Failed to parse the ONNX file.')
ValueError: Failed to parse the ONNX file.

Here is the code I built
TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO)

def GiB(val):
    return val * 1 << 30

# This function builds an engine from a onnx model.
def build_engine(onnx_file_path, precision = 'fp32', dynamic_shapes = None):
    """Takes an ONNX file and creates a TensorRT engine to run inference with"""

    EXPLICIT_BATCH_FLAG = 1 << int(trt.NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag.EXPLICIT_BATCH)

    builder = trt.Builder(TRT_LOGGER)
    network = builder.create_network(EXPLICIT_BATCH_FLAG)
    config = builder.create_builder_config()
    parser = trt.OnnxParser(network, TRT_LOGGER)

    # Parse model file
    TRT_LOGGER.log(TRT_LOGGER.INFO, f'Loading ONNX file from path {onnx_file_path}...')
    with open(onnx_file_path, 'rb') as model:
        TRT_LOGGER.log(TRT_LOGGER.INFO, 'Beginning ONNX file parsing')
        if not parser.parse(model.read()):
            for error in range(parser.num_errors):
                TRT_LOGGER.log(TRT_LOGGER.ERROR, str(parser.get_error(error)))
            raise ValueError('Failed to parse the ONNX file.')
    TRT_LOGGER.log(TRT_LOGGER.INFO, 'Completed parsing of ONNX file')
    TRT_LOGGER.log(TRT_LOGGER.INFO, f'Input number: {network.num_inputs}')
    TRT_LOGGER.log(TRT_LOGGER.INFO, f'Output number: {network.num_outputs}')
    
    
    if dynamic_shapes is not None:
        # set optimization profile for dynamic shape
        profile = builder.create_optimization_profile()
        for i in range(network.num_inputs):
            input = network.get_input(i)
            min_shape = dynamic_shapes['min_shape']
            opt_shape = dynamic_shapes['opt_shape']
            max_shape = dynamic_shapes['max_shape']
            profile.set_shape(input.name, min_shape, opt_shape, max_shape)
        config.add_optimization_profile(profile)

    # We set the builder batch size to be the same as the calibrator's, as we use the same batches
    # during inference. Note that this is not required in general, and inference batch size is
    # independent of calibration batch size.
    config.set_memory_pool_limit(trt.MemoryPoolType.WORKSPACE, GiB(4)) # 1G
    
    if precision == 'fp32':
        pass
    elif precision == 'fp16':
        config.set_flag(trt.BuilderFlag.FP16)
    elif precision == 'int8':
        config.set_flag(trt.BuilderFlag.INT8)
    else:
        raise ValueError('precision must be one of fp32, fp16, or int8')

    # Build engine.
    TRT_LOGGER.log(TRT_LOGGER.INFO, f'Building an engine from file {onnx_file_path}; this may take a while...')
    serialized_engine = builder.build_serialized_network(network, config)
    TRT_LOGGER.log(TRT_LOGGER.INFO, 'Completed creating Engine')
    return serialized_engine
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_feature_engine = build_engine('compile/f2i/video20241014_150313/feature2image.onnx', precision = 'fp16')

The problem is located in the following sentence
    raise ValueError('Failed to parse the ONNX file.')

I tried to print the shape of ONNX
code:
def print_onnx_io_shapes(onnx_file_path):
    model = onnx.load(onnx_file_path)
    print("Model Input and Output Shapes:")

    print("\nInputs:")
    for input_tensor in model.graph.input:
        shape = []
        for dim in input_tensor.type.tensor_type.shape.dim:
            shape.append(dim.dim_value if dim.dim_value else 'dynamic')
        print(f"  - Name: {input_tensor.name}, Shape: {shape}")

    print("\nOutputs:")
    for output_tensor in model.graph.output:
        shape = []
        for dim in output_tensor.type.tensor_type.shape.dim:
            shape.append(dim.dim_value if dim.dim_value else 'dynamic')
        print(f"  - Name: {output_tensor.name}, Shape: {shape}")


result:
Model Input and Output Shapes:

Inputs:
  - Name: l_face_sequences_, Shape: [16, 6, 512, 512]
  - Name: l_audio_feat_, Shape: [16, 512]

Outputs:
  - Name: act_1, Shape: [16, 3, 512, 512]

Also try to simplify the model
code:
def simplified_model_by_path(onnx_file_path):
    onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_file_path)
    simplified_model, check = simplify(onnx_model)
    if check:
        print("ONNX model simplified successfully.")
        simplified_model_path = onnx_file_path.replace('.onnx', '_simplified.onnx')
        onnx.save(simplified_model, simplified_model_path)
        print(f"Simplified model saved at {simplified_model_path}")
    else:
        print("Simplification failed. Please check the model structure.")
    return simplified_model_path


...
feature_engine = build_engine(simplified_model_path, precision='fp16')

result:
[10/30/2024-17:23:15] [TRT] [E] In node 80 with name: stylesync_model_ToRGB_generator_to_rgbs_5_1_541 and operator: stylesync_model_ToRGB_generator_to_rgbs_5_1 (checkFallbackPluginImporter): INVALID_NODE: creator && "Plugin not found, are the plugin name, version, and namespace correct?"
[10/30/2024-17:23:15] [TRT] [E] In node 83 with name: stylesync_model_StyledConv_sub12_1_561 and operator: stylesync_model_StyledConv_sub12_1 (checkFallbackPluginImporter): INVALID_NODE: creator && "Plugin not found, are the plugin name, version, and namespace correct?"
[10/30/2024-17:23:15] [TRT] [E] In node 86 with name: stylesync_model_StyledConv_sub13_1_581 and operator: stylesync_model_StyledConv_sub13_1 (checkFallbackPluginImporter): INVALID_NODE: creator && "Plugin not found, are the plugin name, version, and namespace correct?"
[10/30/2024-17:23:15] [TRT] [E] In node 89 with name: stylesync_model_ToRGB_generator_to_rgbs_6_1_601 and operator: stylesync_model_ToRGB_generator_to_rgbs_6_1 (checkFallbackPluginImporter): INVALID_NODE: creator && "Plugin not found, are the plugin name, version, and namespace correct?"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_convert_engine.py", line 26, in <module>
    feature_engine = build_engine(simplified_model_path, precision='fp16')
  File "SSCODE/convert_tensorrt.py", line 27, in build_engine
    raise ValueError('Failed to parse the ONNX file.')
ValueError: Failed to parse the ONNX file.

I would appreciate it if you could help solve my confusion
